# How to upgrade ruby in RHEL

Tags: rhel, yum

How to upgrade ruby to a new version in RHEL.

When I try - `sudo yum install ruby` It says

> Package ruby-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.x86_64 already installed and latest
>
> version Nothing to do

When I try - `sudo yum install @ruby2.5` It says,

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Repository 'UIM_install' is
>
> missing name in configuration, using id Repository 'debug' is missing
>
> name in configuration, using id Repository nodesource is listed more
>
> than once in the configuration Repository nodesource-source is listed
>
> more than once in the configuration Repository 'opencl' is missing
>
> name in configuration, using id Loading mirror speeds from cached
>
> hostfile Group ruby2.5 does not exist. Error: Nothing to do

I need the latest ruby in my system. What is the solution?

Edit:

I tried `sudo yum update ruby` and gave the following response.

> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> No packages marked for update

Comment: did you try with `yum update ruby`

Comment: Yes, it says - Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No packages marked for update

Comment: In such case I will not recommend to go further. You can update by hand but you will create good mess with the packages. And this can lead to nonfunctional `ruby` installation.

Comment: Okay, but I need a newer version of Ruby as some of the libraries that are used by the project needs later version.

Comment: In such case talk with RH and migrate to RHEL 8 (which support ruby2.5)

Comment: You can get Ruby 2.6 as part of [RedHat Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world#fndtn-ruby). These packages will install into alternate directories, so they can co-exist with the base ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can get newer versions of ruby through [Red Hat Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world#fndtn-ruby).

Once you have the rhscl repo installed you can install the ruby SCL packages. These packages live along side the version of Ruby installed from the base repos, so you won’t use /usr/bin/ruby. The “rh-ruby25” SCL includes Ruby 2.5 but there’s also a Ruby 2.6 (rh-ruby26) if you want a newer one.

The advantage of using SCL is that it is supported by red hat, it gets installed by yum like everything else, and you get security updates. The downside is that it lives along side the base ruby so you need to be careful to load the SCL before using it. Instructions are in the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I never attempt to use the versions of Ruby (or Rails) packaged on any Linux distro, they are almost always too old for what I need - instead, I download whatever version I need using [RVM](https://rvm.io).  If you do this, you'll need to install the newer version of Ruby into a different directory than the distro-provided Ruby, and then you can put that directory into your `$PATH` ahead of the distro-provided binaries if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

RVM instructions for the lazy (slash people who would rather this nonsense actually worked in the first place):

```
$ sudo dnf remove ruby
```

Make sure it doesn't remove any stuff you actually need. Mercifully nothing I had depended on Ruby.

Install RVM (Ruby Version Manager). They make you do a pointless key dance even though it has zero effect on security.

```
gpg2 --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Start a new shell.

Check https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ to see the latest Ruby version.
Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a `--latest` flag. Boo.

```
rvm install 3.3.0
```

It will prompt you for your sudo password so it can install some dependencies (yeay!)

Then it will *build Ruby from source*. Yes, Ruby has the same insane installation UX as Python. I don't remember Go or Rust building themselves from source when I installed them. Boo.

You will get an error:

```
Error running 'run_gem_wrappers regenerate',
please read /home/you/.rvm/log/1706528997_ruby-3.3.0/gemset.wrappers.global.log
```

[Google it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434002/how-to-solve-ruby-installation-is-missing-psych-error). Try the first suggestion (install `libtool`). It was already installed. Try the second suggestion:

```
sudo dnf install libyaml-devel
```

Try again

```
$ rvm install 3.3.0
Already installed ruby-3.3.0.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-3.3.0
```

Lies. Try the `reinstall` version.

Success at last! Who knew upgrading software could be so easy?

Edit: Spoke too soon:

```
$ rvm use 3.3.0

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

Don't do what it says; just move the last line of `.bash_profile` that it added to `.bashrc` instead.

A simple 12 step process!

To save you looking up yet another command:

```
rvm --default use 3.3.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Redhat and centos does not provided the latest version of the various software. This because are LTS (long terms support) operative system. Only security and minor upgrades are released. In order to install an higher version of the software it's better to compile from your self and DON'T REPLACE THE EXISTING VERSION. This because (maybe) the operative system rely on script/tools written with the old particular version. Changing with a different one maybe break something.